# How to delete Azure EventGrid topics?

Tags: azure, events

I created an EventGrid topic like this and chose the wrong location:

`az eventgrid topic create --name esales -l eastus -g mylaketest`

I then noticed I chose the wrong location so I tried to delete the topic with this command:

`az eventgrid topic delete --name esales -g mylaketest`

If I enter this command:

`az eventgrid topic list`

I get this response:

`[]`

So I assume the topic has been deleted.
If I correct my initial command and enter it again, this time with a different location:

`az eventgrid topic create --name esales -l westeurope -g mylaketest`

I get this response:

`(ResourceConflict) Topic with name esales already exists. Choose a different topic name. For more troubleshooting information, please refer to https://aka.ms/EventGridTroubleshooting .  Code: ResourceConflict Message: Topic with name esales already exists. Choose a different topic name. For more troubleshooting information, please refer to https://aka.ms/EventGridTroubleshooting .`

Looks like I need to delete something else or I missed anything?

Comment: It sometimes takes a few hours for the deletion to be propagated to all systems

Answer (score 0):

*I tried to create an event grid topic according to your requirements and was able to successfully execute it with the same name in a new location once it was deleted.*

***Verify the following:***

*1. It takes much longer to delete an event grid topic than it does to create one. Wait for it to finish, otherwise it will throw the same error that you received.
2. In addition to your creation, if any other topic exists in any other resource group created by someone else, this error is thrown.*

`az eventgrid topic create -l EastUs`:

```bash
az eventgrid topic create -g <ResourceGroup> --name mytopic -l EastUs
```

[image]

`az eventgrid topic delete`:

```bash
az eventgrid topic delete -g <ResourceGroup> --name mytopic
```

[image]

`az eventgrid topic list`:

```bash
az eventgrid topic list -g <ResourceGroup>
```

[image]

`az eventgrid topic create -l westus2`:

```bash
az eventgrid topic create -g <ResourceGroup> --name mytopic -l westus2
```

[image]

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/eventgrid/topic?view=azure-cli-latest)

Comment: I think I ve created the same topic name in a different ressource group, inside the same subscription. Because I am following a tutorial in a book. I deleted that ressource group because I wanted to start over. Is there anything I can do now?

Comment: Anyways you deleted that resource group right so it will work if you are creating in a new one with different location. Can you try once?

Comment: I just created a topic in eastus, tried to create the same topic in the same resource group in westeurope and I got the resource conflict error. I then deleted the topic and tried again and it worked instant. So I think my problem is, the topic "esales" existed in a resource group which I deleted. And now the topic name is reserved.

Comment: Ok. I hope it is working now as expected.

Comment: Still it is not creating? @DirkSachse

Comment: I can now create and delete the topic name "esales". It took almost exactly 24h for it to be gone. Thank you for your support!